# Why do we need $F \subset E\;$ for $f(E)\,\backslash\, f(F) \subset f(E \;\backslash\ F)$ to hold?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**Theorem:**

If $f: A\to B$ is a function and $E$ and $F$ are subsets of $A$, then $f(E)\,\backslash\, f(F) \subset f(E \;\backslash\ F)\,$ if $F \subset E$.

I proved this theorem and my proof is exactly the same as the one in the book. But the proof doesn't use the fact that $F \subset E$ and I don't understand why it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that this fact is true regardless of whether $F\subset E$.

My best guess is that some books only define the set difference $E\setminus F$ in the situation when $F\subset E$. Personally I don't have any problem defining $E\setminus F$ in general, but some authors might find it confusing to their intended readership to do so.

Comment: I just checked and you are right, the author put it in the definition. Thanks!